# UITabBarController didSelect and shouldSelect no longer called after presenting and dismissing webView

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a subclass of UITabBarController declared as follows

```
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        self.currentTabIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

        if self.currentTabIndex == 2 {
            let reportVC = UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tabBarController) as? ReportsViewController

            if let reportsViewController = reportVC {
                if reportsViewController.reportTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 {
                    reportVC?.reportTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)

                    let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController
                    let destinationVC = navVC?.viewControllers.last as? ReportsViewController

                    return (destinationVC != nil) ? false : true
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let newIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

        let tabIndexList = [0, 1]

        if self.currentTabIndex == newIndex && tabIndexList.contains(newIndex)  {
            let hbgViewController = (newIndex == 2)
                ? tabBarController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
                : tabBarController.selectedViewController as! DLHamburguerNavigationController

            switch newIndex {
            case 0:
                let alertsViewController = hbgViewController.viewControllers[0] as! AlertsViewController
                alertsViewController.alertsTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
                break
            case 1:
                let newsViewController = hbgViewController.viewControllers[0] as! NewsViewController
                newsViewController.newsTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When a user taps on the currently selected tab, the tableview scrolls to the top. This works as expected, however, when the user taps on an item in the table view, a webview is loaded with a remote news article. After the view is dismissed, the above code no longer works,
Navigating tabs work, but `didSelect` and `shouldSelect` no longer get called. I have no idea why.

Here's how the webview is presented:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newImageSource = self.newsArticles?[indexPath.row].getImageUrl(type: Article.FireNewsImageType.NewsFeed)

    let articleURLString = self.newsArticles?[indexPath.row].url

    let webViewController = GDWebViewController()
    webViewController.title = self.newsArticles?[indexPath.row].title
    let webVCNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webViewController)

    webViewController.showsToolbar = false
    webViewController.progressIndicatorStyle = .both
    webViewController.loadURLWithString(articleURLString!)

    let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(NewsViewController.dismissVC))
    webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancel

    self.present(webVCNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

GDWebViewController can be found here if required:
https://gist.github.com/elimence/91cf35dfe677b38b23a27c6d54d44285

Any pointers would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Hi, did you set the `TabbarViewController`'s `delegate` to itself?

Comment: @ZonilyJame damn! thats the reason. I set it in viewDidLoad and unset in viewWillDisappear, but I forget to re-set it in viewWillAppear.
I'm super grateful :)
If you'll provide an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're not setting the `UITabBarController`'s `delegate` to your `TabbarViewController` class

You can either place it on `viewDidLoad()` or another part of your code like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // this code right here.
    self.delegate = self
}
```